# Grafana Timeseries Panel: How to change color of annotations bar based on a tag

Tags: grafana, grafana-api, grafana-alerts

I am using Grafana version 8.1.0 and have a timeseries panel on which annotations are added using HTTP create annotation API and GUI both.

I want to change the color of the annotation bar based on tags added to that annotation.

I have tried to go through documentation but have not found a way to do it. Could someone help me out with this? I think this is a very basic requirement and I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it's not implemented yet, as you can see on this [open issue from 2018](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/12290).
You can also see from the [annotations API documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/annotations/) that it's not possible yet.